# Adding an image in placeholder of .hbs ember template file

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I want to add an image to a .hbs template file in ember. I dont build applications I'm just simply trying to style up the basic todo list app.

```
<section class='todoapp'>
  <header id='header'>
    <img src="../assets/logo2.png" />
    {{input type='text'
            class='new-todo'
            placeholder='What else is in your wallet?'
            value=newTitle
            enter='createTodo'}}
  </header>
```

My goal is to add an image next to the placeholder field before someone clicks into the inputer field. I'm assuming I cant add it with the value so do I do something with the .new-todo class in css to drop the image in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css:

```
background: url('[url]') no-repeat; background-position: 10px;
```

Adjust the background pos pixels.

If you want to hide the image when the element is focused, use :focus, in css and set `background: none;`:

```
.element-class:hover { background: none; }
```

Also it's possible make a div with **contenteditable** in HTML, and in it you can create a new placeholder function (a function to add own made placeholder in element with contenteditable) from the javascript, and so you can add images to placeholder.

Comment: Hey, the right way to add image is using a background img in the input with css, I did a test. But, remember, there's a duplicate question of this.